# does filtering queryset in django query database every time?

Tags: python, django, database, django-queryset

Imagine I have the following code:

```py
qs = Users.objects.all()

list = []
for i in range(10):
    list.append(qs.filter(age=i))
```

here the filter is called 10 times, does it connect to database 10 times or the first time filter is being used, the `qs` is assigned (due to being lazy) and the filters are applied locally (total of one database connection)?

Comment: You do not make any query at all at the moment. `QuerySet`s are lazy, so that means that it waits until you *use* the queryset. If you later would iterate multiple times over the same queryset, it wll make the query *once*, store the result in the `QuerySet`, and thus use that result the next time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When are Django Querysets executed in the view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70038002/when-are-django-querysets-executed-in-the-view)

Answer (score 6):

> here the filter is called 10 times, does it connect to database 10 times or the first time filter is being used.

Django does not perform a query when you call `.filter(…)`. You only construct a `QuerySet`. It is only when you *consume* a `QuerySet`, for example by *iterating* over it, subscripting, or calling `len(…)` on the object, you make a query.

If you thus later in the process iterate over all querysets, for example:

```
for myqs in mylist:
    for obj in myqs:
        print(obj)
```

you will make **ten separate queries**, a query for each queryset that is evaluated.

If you iterate over the queryset, then Django will run the query on the database, and store the result, the list of records, in the `QuerySet`. This thus means that if you iterate a *second* time over this queryset, it will not run the query a second time, but *reuse* the results cached in the `QuerySet`.

Note that subscripting, i.e. `myqueryset[0]`, will make a query to fetch a single object. If you do this a second time, it will again run the query on the database.

Certain technologies, like [*Haxl* <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/facebook/Haxl) have been implemented to "batch queries", and in case one of the results is necessary, all queries are combined in the query to the database. But as far as I know, Django has no support for Haxl at the moment.

Comment: Though this is correct, this is also not very useful in understanding what happens in this sample. This sample creates 10 different querysets. Thus, eventually accessing the data will indeed perform 10 queries.

Comment: @spectras: if you later iterate over all the querysets in the list, then it will indeed make 10 queries.