# When are Django Querysets executed in the view?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I read the Querysets Django docs regarding querysets being lazy, but still am a bit confused here.

So in my view, I set a queryset to a variable like so

```
players = Players.objects.filter(team=team)
```

Later on, I have a sorting mechanism that I can apply

```
sort = '-player_last_name'


if pts > 20:
    players = players.filter(pts__gte = pts).order_by(sort)
else:
    players = players.filter(pts__lte = pts).order_by(sort)

if ast < 5:
   players = players.filter(asts__lte = ast).order_by(sort)
else:
   players = players.filter(asts__gte = ast).order_by(sort)

context = {players: players)

return render(request, '2021-2022/allstars.html', context)
```

What I want to know is, when is the players queryset evaluated? is it when each page is rendered, or everytime I assign the queryset to a variable? Because if it's the former, then I can just apply the .order_by(sort) chain and the previous applications are redundant.

Comment: If you "consume" the queryset. You consume a queryset by enumerating over it, call `.get(...)` or `.aggregate(..)`, cal `len(..)` over it, etc.

Comment: In this specific case, none of the queryset's are evaluated, or at least not *before* you pass these to the template. If the template for example enumerates over the queryset, then it is evaluatd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QuerySet`s are evaluated if you "*consume*" the queryset. You consume a queryset by enumerating over it, call [**`.get(…)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get),  [**`.exists(…)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exists), [**`.aggregate(…)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate) or  [**`.count(…)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#count), check the truthiness (for example with `if myqueryset:` or `bool(queryset)`, or call `len(…)` over it, etc. As a rule of thumb, it gets evaluated if you perform an action on it such that the result is no longer a `QuerySet`.

If you enumerate over it, or you call `len(…)` the result is cached in the `QuerySet`, so calling it a second time, or enumerating over it after you have called `len(…)` will *not* make another trip to the database.

In this specific case, none of the `QuerySet`s are evaluated before you make the call to the `render(…)` function. If in the template you for example use `{% if players %}`, or `{% for players %}`, `{{ players|length }}`, or `{{ players.exists }}`, then it will evaluate the queryset.

Comment: Got it, this makes sense. So for example, calling methods such as `.get(…), .exists(…), .aggregate(…) or .count(…)`, convert the queryset to a boolean value, or another datatype, thus its no longer a queryset, so the queryset gets evaluated? What about `.annotate(...)`, is that a method that evaluates the queryset as well? I'm assuming its best practice for my situation then to just place the `.orderby` on the entire queryset before passing it through context, in that cause, to reduce redundancy. And `.orderby()` call doesn't consume the queryset, just orders it, thus it won't evaluate it.

Comment: @nick_rinaldi: no, `.annotate(..)` constructs a new queryset that is a variant of the old one with as extra task to make annotations. Both the old and the new one are not evaluated if not necessary.

Comment: @nick_rinaldi: the `.order_by(..)` indeed will not consume the queryset, hence it will not make a database query (unless of course you later evaluate the queryset)

Comment: Thanks, that answers that. I have another quick question I was hoping you could help me with. I'm refactoring code, and currently checking whether certain querysets are evaluated or not. To do this, I'm checking their `._result_cache` attribute. If it's None, that I presume it hasn't been evaluated. However, I noticed that if I run `connection.queries` in the shell, it's displaying SQL queries being made from querysets that I understood weren't to be evaluated yet. Does `connection.queries` just display every SQL query that will be made, regardless if the queryset is evaluated or not?

Comment: @nick_rinaldi: no, `connection.queries` shows the queries that have been made to the database. Note that if you *print* a `QuerySet` it will also make a query, since it shows its results when you call `str(..)` or `repr(..)` on the queryset.

Comment: So I think where I'm having a disconnect is the difference between a queryset being evaluated, and a queries made to the database. Certaintly, if `players = Players.objects.filter(team='Knicks')` will query the database for any player on the Knicks team. However, apparently setting `players` = to that queryset doesn't evaluate the query? Isn't a query made to the database technically an 'evaluation'?  My goal is to improve performance, so thats only why I'm getting clarification. I know this is off-topic, I appreciate your input Willem.

Comment: @nick_rinaldi: setting it to `players = ...` does not evaluate the query no. But if you later print the query, enumerate over the query in the template, etc. it will make that query since at that time the data is necessary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239408/discussion-between-nick-rinaldi-and-willem-van-onsem).

Answer (score 1):

Django queries are designed to be "lazy" - that is. they don't run the database query until something requests actual data. Queries can be modified by the addition of filtering and other similar functions.

For example, the following code requests all `TeamMember` objects when the search string is `'all'`, but otherwise adds a filter to restrict names to those matching the given search.

```
    squad_list = TeamMember.objects(state__in={"Hired", "Joined", "Staff", "Recruiting"})
    if squadname != 'all':
        squad_list = squad_list(squad__icontains=squadname.lower())
```

When the `squadlist` query is finally executed it will retrieve the required record. Dopes this help?